# DbContext Update vs EntityState Modified

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, http-put

What is the difference between `_context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified` and `_context.Entity.Update(entity)` in ASP.NET EF Core? For example:

```
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PutStudent(Student student)
{
     **_context.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;**
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return student;
}
```

```
    
[HttpPut]
public async Task<ActionResult<Student>> PutStudent(Student student)
{
     **_context.Student.Update(student);**
     await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
     return student;
}
```

Comment: As I know, no difference. But both will update ALL non PK properties in database. And if there is a big table and a bunch of indexes - you may encounter performance issues.

Comment: I believe you can set an entity or property as modified even without changing it. Where as update will check if a property has changed before setting it as modified. Meaning setting an entity as modified is forcing an update where as simply updating the entity may not result in a database call. I might be entirely wrong on this - it's been known to happen.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Setting an entity's state to`Modified` will mark all of the entity's scalar properties as modified, meaning that `SaveChanges` will generate an update statement updating all mapped table fields except the key field(s).

Not asked, but a single property can also be marked as `Modified`:

```
_context.Entry(student).Property(s => s.Name).IsModified = true;
```

This will also set the entity's state as modified.

The `Update` method is quite different, see the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbset-1.update?view=efcore-6.0):

> Begins tracking the given entity (...)
> For entity types with generated keys if an entity has its primary key value set then it will be tracked in the Modified state. If the primary key value is not set then it will be tracked in the Added state. This helps ensure new entities will be inserted, while existing entities will be updated. An entity is considered to have its primary key value set if the primary key property is set to anything other than the CLR default for the property type.

This can be very convenient in *disconnected scenarios* in which new and updated entities are attached to a context. EF will figure out which entities are `Added` and which are `Modified`.

Another difference is that the `Update` method also traverses nested entities. For example, if `Exams` is a collection in the `Student` class, updating a `Student` will also mark its `Exams` as `Modified`, or `Added` where their keys aren't set.

Not documented, but worth mentioning, if a `Student` and its `Exams` are attached as `Unchanged` then the `Update` method will only set the `Student`'s state to `Modified`, not the `Exams`.

Comment: I'm assuming `_context.Entry(student).Property(s => s.Name).IsModified = true;`, will on make a change on the specific property, do you know? The [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetracking.propertyentry.ismodified?view=efcore-6.0#microsoft-entityframeworkcore-changetracking-propertyentry-ismodified) doesn't seem to specify.