# Entity Framework doesn't seem to be able to properly link new navigation properties on updates

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, navigation-properties, ef-core-6.0

When I'm creating new entities, I'm able to use the unit of work pattern and create parent and children at the same time while EF handles the relationships and either saves the whole result or rolls it back.

When I'm doing an update via `DbSet<Xyz>.Update(xyz)`, and xyz has been updated such that navigation property (`Apple`) is now a new entity (`newApple`), I can't find any way to establish this relationship. If I manually call `DbSet<Apple>.Add(newApple)`, the new apple is added to the database. EF just didn't do anything with the fact that I've set `xyz.Apple = newApple`, and I'd expect it to be able to based on how it handles creates. I also tried setting `xyz.AppleId = default`, but that just sets it to null if there is a value and doesn't do anything if there wasn't one.

What am I missing?

note:

1. Yes, I'm pulling the `Apple` property. That doesn't seem to make a difference.
2. I have tried setting the specific property's IsModified value to true as well. That is actually what I originally hoped to do as I usually only want to update a few fields at a time. When that didn't work, I reverted back to using the Update method which also failed with the exact same issues (setting it to a default value if I cleared out the `AppleId` property and set `xyz.Apple = new Apple`).
3. I've disabled AutoDetectChanges. I didn't think to mention it because I've done this for the last 7 or so years. Not sure that this makes a difference because my goal is to only explicitly inform EF of what I want it to operate on (I know that's not the recommended approach).

edit: Here's an actual code block so I can beat the "didn't try hard enough" accusations after staying up till 5am trying to make this work :)

```
// this just sets the  tree's apple id to the default value (null or 0) and adds the new apple to the db
var tree = db.Trees.Include(x => x.Apple).FirstOrDefault();
var newApple = new Apple();
db.Apples.Add(newApple);
tree.AppleId = default;
tree.Apple = newApple;
db.Trees.Update(tree);
db.SaveChanges(); 


// this adds the new apple to the db and doesn't modify the tree at all
var tree = db.Trees.Include(x => x.Apple).FirstOrDefault();
var newApple = new Apple();
db.Apples.Add(newApple);
tree.AppleId = default;
tree.Apple = newApple;

db.Entry(entity).Navigation(nameof(Apple)).IsModified = true;
// note: I've also tried setting AppleId property to IsModified just in case, but that will null it out. Without that, it doesn't change at all
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: This is objectively the downvote reason: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful". It is unclear because it doesn't show any code. A description of code is never enough to see what's really going on. Also, please try to understand what he `Update` method does. I consider this a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71594676/861716.

Comment: @user15716642 Please [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others.
Then see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056 for SQL related questions.

Comment: Just look at the popup text of the downvote button. May I remind you that I didn't DV and so far no one (any more)? That said, you should remove `tree.AppleId = default;
`.

Comment: Looks like my earlier comment was removed, but I explained that the linked question is unrelated and gave examples showing I already know that. I explained that both methods of applying updates yield the same results. Setting `AppleId` to default was just an additional attempt to force it to reset because not setting it basically just applies no change at all for me. There was a downvote before that I don't see anymore though.

I can provide an example, but all I've done is disable autodetectchanges because I like to explicitly inform EF of my changes. I just don't know how to do that here.

Comment: @user15716642 You should add this information to your question as it might be important. Also, add the MCVE.

Comment: In EF Core, the UoW patter is already implemented by DbContext and means creating the DbContext in a `using` block and calling `SaveChanges` immediately before exiting the block. I assume the `using` block is there but omitted? And the three snippets are three independent calls?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yea all I meant was that I like to create/update a lot of entities at once and am used to having SaveChanges handle all the relationship mapping for me such that if one piece fails, the whole thing fails. I tend to favor that over explicitly starting new transactions.

Comment: @Progman I did mention all of it but forgot the autodetectchanges piece as I've always disabled it and forgot it was a factor. I just updated the question with it - good suggestion, ty.

Comment: In a similar case in my own code, this is enough: `var newApple = new Apple(); tree.Apple = newApple; db.SaveChanges();`. But so far, still a great deal of essential information is lacking, like the class model and mapping code. We still can't reproduce your case, which, BTW, also works in my case, but has far too many redundant lines.

Comment: There is no mapping code for this as it uses the EF defaults which are able to relate Apple with AppleId automatically. But I am trying to create a repo which encompasses all of the EF configurations since that seems to be the difference. We have a shared internal codebase where some settings are changed so it's taking a bit. The main difference could be either in that AutoDetectChanges is disabled. But if it is, I wonder which property/entity I need to inform EF about in order to make this work. Hm