# How to reference a disconnected entity in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I would like to create a post referencing an existing user to my database:

```cs
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options) { }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}

public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey(nameof(UserId))]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This works if the user is obtained through the same context. But I would like to know if it is possible to achieve this by providing a "disconnected entity" as shown in the example below:

```cs
class Program
{
    IServiceProvider ServiceProvider { get; init; }

    public Program(string[] args)
    {
        var app = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
        ServiceProvider = app.Services;

        var user = CreateUser();

        using var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>();

        var post = new Post()
        {
            // Because an user with this ID already exists an exception is thrown when trying to save the post!
            User = user
        };

        db.Posts.Add(post);
        db.SaveChanges(); // <-- Exception

        app.Run();
    }

    User CreateUser()
    {
        using var scope = ServiceProvider.CreateScope();
        var db = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<Context>();

        var user = new User() { Username = "Ocean" };

        db.Users.Add(user);

        db.SaveChanges();

        return user;
    }
}
```

This throws the following exception:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
>
> SqliteException: SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Users.Id'

To figure out what's happening I looked at

```
db.ChangeTracker.DebugView.ShortView
```

and to my surprise it appears that Entity Framework is trying to re-create the provided user object - even though its ID already exists.

How can I tell Entity Framework to only save the foreign key (`UserId`) for that post?

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, if I retrieve the user from the context, I can reference it to my post without problems. And I'm not trying to update anything, just creating a new post.

Comment: Use `db.Posts.Update(post)`. It figures out what's new and existing.

Comment: @GertArnold Oh that works even better! If you post this as answer, I will mark it as solved. Thank you!

Comment: Since my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71593424/861716) basically explains everything you may consider selecting that question as duplicate, even though the question is a bit different.

Answer (score 0):

For any future readers. Just attach your disconnected entity to your context:

```cs
db.Attach(user);
```